# (R-Shiny) How to set a beginning value in slider input automatically?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to do some sliders with a begin value and after modify them. I'm using the updateSliderInput to set the value but,  when I try to modify them, them come back to the same value. 
How to fix that?

Comment: Cold you please share some of your code. Especially the Server function Please.

Comment: your problem probably comes from the fact that you have placed the `updateSliderInput ` in a part of the code that is dependent of the same variable. that means every time you change the value of the slider it runs the code once again and resets the value. But to tell you exactly why this happens we need to see your server code. and preferbly also the UI

Comment: You were right, I really was placing the updateSliderInput in a wrong place. I changed that so the problem was fixed. Thank you 

Now I have another question.
How can I do an updateSlider with many vars?  I mean, I have 28 sliders and I need to change them evert time the selectInput changes, so, do I have to create 28 updateSliders? There is another way to do that?

Comment: Hi, @Daniel. Please post this as new Qustion with some minimal example - that makes it a lot easier for others to help you - and I will for sure take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

To set a starting value update the `value` parameter. Below is an example of a slider which is called `decimal` with display text *Decimal* which has values ranging from 0 to 1. It starts at .5 and each step is .1.

```
  sliderInput("decimal", "Decimal:",
              min = 0, max = 1,
              value = 0.5, step = 0.1),
```